# How to change length of word by loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change length of word in every field in column of my dataframe. I have prepared some solution but it didn't work. Where is the problem? I got the error.

Error:
TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Df:

```
    lokalny_id  url year    fid status
0   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
1   12  73678_919385_M-33-23-A-r-6-2.tif    2023    2   z.
2   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
3   13  73678_919385_M-33-23-O-k-2-3.tif    2020    3   z.
4   1234    73678_919317_M-33-35-D-a-1-4.tif    2022    123 w.
5   15  73678_919385_M-33-23-B-z-1-7.tif    2012    5   z.
6   17  73678_919385_M-33-23-D-c-2-9.tif    2013    6   o.
```

My code:

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/ja/Inne/Desktop/my.xlsx')

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    correct_word = row['url'][13:]
    row['url'] = row['url'].replace(correct_word)
```

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: and also post the current output you are having, when you say it doesn't work

Comment: I got the error: TypeError: replace expected at least 2 arguments, got 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using pandas apply maybe more straightforward:

```py
df["url"] = df["url"].apply(lambda x: x[13:])
```